# Input type submit with multiple functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts

I recently discovered the use of userscripts and since my work has to do with repetitive tasks on a website, I needed to create a button that would hold multiple functionality. The code I have so far is creating the button and applies the function doAll which is selecting the two radio buttons. After executing this I also want the button to have the ability to submit. How can I implement it? Thanks in advance.

```
var input=document.createElement("input");
input.type="button";
input.value="Save";
input.onclick = doAll;
document.body.appendChild(input); 


function doAll() {
    $('[id^=radio1_]').prop("checked", true)
    $('[id^=radio2_]').prop("checked", true)
    }
```

Comment: Add `$("#formID").submit()` to `doAll`.

Comment: @Barnar thanks for your reply. In case I don't know the formID is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Why don't you know the form ID? How do you know which form you want to submit when they click on the button? It's not in a form.

Comment: I only know the form action which is as follows: `<form action="/photo/edit?id=1234"`

Comment: Do you want to use AJAX instead of doing normal form submission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a selector to find the form with the action you want:

```
function doAll() {
    $('[id^=radio1_], [id^=radio2_]').prop("checked", true);
    $('form[action="/photo/edit?id=1234"]').submit();
}
```

Comment: Hey @Barmar and thanks for your time. I checked this on chrome's console tool and it works perfectly fine. So my last question: how could this be implemented for multiple photo ids instead of the case of one?

Comment: You mean submit all the forms whose action begins with `/photo/edit`? You can use an attribute prefix selector: `$('form[action^="/photo/edit"]')`. You should familiarize yourself with the attribute selectors, see https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/